# How to print the error codes during authentication of google cloud platform using service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, service-accounts

I am using google cloud storage and bigquery services of google cloud platform. I'm using service account to authenticate my application and cloud sdk to perform any actions on them.As of now, I'm able to connect and also able to perform any actions. I am curious to know that let suppose if my service account file get modified or somehow the path of that file get lost. Is there is anyway to verify my service account whether it is valid account or not and based on that I can print my code(error codes) and take action on that?

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Cloud SDK commands, you can request additional debugging information:

> 1. Google Cloud [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) has two flags that give user control over information that are displayed:

[--log-http](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--log-http) Logs all HTTP server requests

[--verbosity](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) Can display error or critical`

> 2. Cloud Storage [gsutil has two options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/TopLevelCommandLineOptions):

-D requests additional debug information

-DD requests full HTTP upstream payload

However, to have greater control over processes and errors, use [Google Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries), to [authenticate and access Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication).